# Include default constraint names in generation of update script

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, constraints, database-project, schema-compare

I'm using a **SQL Server Database Project** with Visual Studio 2012 and have the following problem when comparing and generating an update script:

In Visual Studio, I add a column with a default constraint, for example:

```sql
[NewColumn] NVARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT [DF_ExistingTable_NewColumn] NOT NULL DEFAULT N''
```

Unfortunately, the name of the default constraint does not appear when:

- Comparing (*Schema Compare*) my project with the actual database
- Generating an update script (from within the *Schema Compare*)

The created update script contains the following script (no constraint name):

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExistingTable]
    ADD [NewColumn] NVARCHAR (50) DEFAULT N'' NOT NULL;
```

This seems like a major oversight, so I'm wondering where to find the magic switch to include the names of default constraints in all database operations.

Answer (score 5):

I think the order may be off in your definition. Try moving the "NOT NULL" part to the end of the line instead of in the middle of your constraint definition.

```
[NewColumn] NVARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT [DF_ExistingTable_NewColumn] DEFAULT N'' NOT NULL
```

Comment: I just did the same mistake. Thanks, NOT NULL must obviously be in the end.